# How to get GMT format with time difference

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a date format like this **2019-07-16 14:51:40 GMT+05:30.**

```
NSDate *exactDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss X";
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
```

> **Output** : 2019-07-17 15:18:23 +0530
>
> **Expected Output** : 2019-07-16 14:51:40 GMT+05:30

Comment: Use  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz"  instead of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss X"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `X` with `ZZZZ` or `OOOO`

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ";
```

Source: [unicode.org : Date Format Pattern Examples](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Pattern_Examples)